# Is there a legally binding agreement between a country and the United States that prevents it from letting China build a military base within it?

Tags: united-states, china, international

> In terms of Saudi-Chinese relations, Washington has three main
> demands, according to the Wall Street Journal:
>
> “assurances that Riyadh will use U.S. dollars, not Chinese currency,
> to price oil sales”,
>
> **“assurances from Saudi Arabia that it won’t allow China to build
> military bases in the kingdom”, and**
>
> “limitations on Saudi Arabia using technology developed by China’s
> Huawei”.

https://geopoliticaleconomy.com/2023/08/10/us-saudi-arabia-sell-oil-dollars-chinese-yuan/

The U.S. allegedly asked Saudi Arabia to not let China install military bases within its borders, I was reading that and I was wondering if there are any legally binding agreement between the United States and another country that doesn't allow it to let China build a military bases within it. I couldn't find anything of the sort.

Comment: Not my DV, but note that "assurances" generally means less than a legally binding (i.e. just politically binding) commitment. Although in the case of a theoretically absolute monarchy like Saudi Arabia, that may a bit more murky to tell apart.

Comment: See e.g. the assurances that Maldives provided to India in that regard (some years ago) https://www.voanews.com/a/maldives-says-no-to-chinese-bases/2910908.html

Comment: OTOH, when it comes to dual-use naval facilities, one can issue vaguely plausible denials while building them nonetheless (as is the case with Cambodia)

https://www.voanews.com/a/cambodian-ream-naval-base-modernized-by-china-nears-completion-defense-ministry/7198994.html

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that Saudi, IIRC, had some issues with the original US bases, back in 1991.  That was one of the causes for the Bin Laden fatwa, unbelievers despoiling the Holy Land and all that.  Things have changed since then, but Chinese bases might run into domestic political/religious opposition.  Maybe, maybe not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

##### Yes, the [Compacts of Free Association (COFA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_of_Free_Association) between the United States and the Pacific island nations of Palau, Micronesia and the Marshall Islands.

Under them, these countries outsource their defense to the United States, who has the responsibility to defend them. In return, the US can freely move troops through their borders, set up military bases and exclude other militaries from entering. The particular passages read:

> The Government of the United States has full authority and responsibility for security and defense matters in or relating to the Marshall Islands and the Federated States of Micronesia.
>
> This authority and responsibility includes:
>
> - the obligation to defend the Marshall Islands and the Federated States of Micronesia and their peoples from attack or threats thereof as the United States and its citizens are defended;
> - **the option to foreclose access to or use of the Marshall Islands and the Federated States of Micronesia by military personnel or for the military purposes of any third country;** and
> - the option to establish and use military areas and facilities in the Marshall Islands and the Federated States of Micronesia, subject to the terms of the separate agreements referred to in Sections 321 and 323.
>
> The Government of the United States confirms that it shall act in accordance with the principles of international law and the Charter of the United Nations in the exercise of this authority and responsibility.

<sup>[Section 231 of the Compact of Free Association with Micronesia and the Marshall Islands](http://www.fsmlaw.org/compact/t03art01.htm)</sup>

and

> **The territorial jurisdiction of the Republic of Palau shall be completely foreclosed to the military
> forces and personnel or for the military purposes of any nation except the United States of
> America, and as provided for in Section 312.**

<sup>Section 231 of the [Compact of Free Association with Palau](https://pw.usembassy.gov/wp-content/uploads/sites/282/2017/05/rop_cofa.pdf)</sup>

Like most treaties, these treaties are not binding forever and could be terminated, so I strongly doubt there is a treaty that would prevent Chinese bases forever and against all opposition by the host country. But since termination of a COFA requires either US agreement or a plebiscite, it is rather difficult for these treaties in particular.

Comment: How is that legally binding? They can just chose to abolish that treaty and let China in.

Comment: @JoeW: no international agreement is legally binding in any other sense. Westphalian sovereignty and all that.

Comment: @JoeW and the US could choose to send in some troops to support the local democracy ;)

Comment: @Fizz Yes, that was the point of my comment. The answer is saying that there is a legally binding agreement when that isn't the case.

Comment: @JonathanReez And that isn't a legally binding agreement.

Comment: This is a case of suzerainty, so I don't think this is what the question is asking for.

Comment: @JoeW It's still a treaty that they signed until they abolish it.  So it answers the Q.  Which incidentally might not deserve its DVs as this answer shows that it can be done.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica And if a country decides to not honor that treaty there isn't and sort of "legal proceeding"  that can be used to force them to honor it. Granted that does depend somewhat on the country.

Comment: But as that has been noted upteen times around here, including by the comment under yours, that **is** precisely how treaties work.  And since there is no "World Court" it will remain how treaties work, meaning that your "legal proceedings" just don't exist.  Not in this case.  Not in other cases either, unless someone applies force to get it.  **This is as "legally binding" as it gets**.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Yes, there is  nothing legally binding about a treaty which is my objection

Comment: [Treaties as Binding International Obligation | ASIL](https://www.asil.org/insights/volume/2/issue/4/treaties-binding-international-obligation): *Contrary to Mr. Bolton's assertion, it is clear that treaties are legally binding in their internal operation. The members of the United Nations, including the United States, have said as much when they established the U.N.'s principal judicial organ, the International Court of Justice.*